Sending email to two supervisors
I found an open postdoc position which is a project with two supervisors. I sent an inquiry email to one of supervisors 5 days ago about the position, but I have not received a reply from her yet. Is it Ok to send same email to another supervisor ( and I mention that I have sent an email to his colleague) in order to ask my questions?

I would say that 5 days is not much (especially if it includes the weekend, even tho academic tend to consider weekends as workdays). I would wait a bit more, they may have just not processed your message (if the deadline is very close, then maybe you can send an email to the other supervisor)

In this period of the year, researchers may have conferences/seminars. So, 5 days are ok.

Five days isn’t long in academic time, especially now(June). But you can send mail to the second person.
It would probably have been better to send mail to both initially but it is too late for that now.
Mention in the email that you have already contacted the first person.
